# wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Tags: java, jvm, 32bit-64bit

I have a java application which tries to load external libraries but I keep getting the same exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /test/software/libraries/libraries/bin/libxejni.so: ld.so.1: java: fatal: /test/software/libraries/libraries/bin/libxejni.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088) ~[?:1.7.0_79]
```

This is appartantly got to do with a 32-bit JVM trying to load a 64-bit native shared library. However my java version is 64 bit

> java version "1.7.0_79" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_79-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

The applicaton is build using maven, anyone have any clue what the issue could be here?

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that the version of Java that's *actually running* is a 64-bit one? Just running `java -version` from the command line won't necessarily show the JVM that's being used by your application (e.g. if it's a web app).

Comment: Yes it's being deployed on a solaris server with java 1.7 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Check if `libxejni.so` the application need to load is 32-bit or 64-bit, then specify `java -d32` or `java -d64` option for 32-bit or 64-bit `so`, respectively, when running your application.

Comment: This is not running locally, this is running on a server i'm unclear of how I can specify this. Only java config I can find is the JAVA_HOME setting. would "testenv/software/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java -d64" work as my JAVA_HOME?

Comment: What is your server? You need to check the server configuration. Usually, the right place to set `-d64` is in `JAVA_OPTIONS`

Comment: We have it set here wrapper.java.additional.4=-d64 and JVM is 64 bit but still issue

Comment: Turned out a duplicate wrapper.java.additional.4 was causing the -d64 to be overwritten. That was the issue.